# getting selected value as undefined

Tags: jquery, jsf, undefined, selectonemenu

JSF code (dropdown menu populated with student names)

```
 <h:selectOneMenu  class="form-control" id="sels" onchange="getSelectedStud()">
       <f:selectItems value="#{user.allstuds}" var="user" itemValue="#{user.std_id}" itemLabel="#{user.name}" />
 </h:selectOneMenu >
```

JS code

```
 function getSelectedStud(){
             var sel_val = $("#sels :selected").val();
            $("#los").append("<option>"+ sel_val +"</option>");
        }
```

also tried this JS

```
function getSelectedStud(){
                 var sel_val = $("#sels").val();
                $("#los").append("<option>"+ sel_val +"</option>");
            }
```

can i get itemValue and itemLabel ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `:selected`, jQuery will give you the value currently selected.

```
function getSelectedStud(){
    var sel_val = $("#sels").val();
    $("#los").append("<option>"+ sel_val +"</option>");
}
```

But I'm not sure if `itemValue` will be translated as `value`, or is a custom attribute? If so, you would need `.attr("itemValue");`.